# How may I test in CakePHP with Pest

Tags: php, testing, model-view-controller, cakephp, php-pest

My problem:
How my I test some MVC part with Pest in CakePHP, for example:
When I´m use PHPUnit, I´ll  type:

> public class ItemTest extends TestCase

And it will show what thing that I wanna test, but how do that with Pest?

(Obs.: I´m really new on tests, so I accept anything that will make me improve :) )

Answer (score 1):

After you [installed Pest](https://pestphp.com/docs/installation) you just have to follow its syntax and documentation, removing all the OOP code and just using [`test()` or `it()`](https://pestphp.com/docs/writing-tests). The file name will be the same. This is an example from CakePHP docs:

```
class ArticlesTableTest extends TestCase
{
    public $fixtures = ['app.Articles'];

    public function setUp()
    {
        parent::setUp();
        $this->Articles = TableRegistry::getTableLocator()->get('Articles');
    }

    public function testFindPublished()
    {
        $query = $this->Articles->find('published');
        $this->assertInstanceOf('Cake\ORM\Query', $query);
        $result = $query->enableHydration(false)->toArray();
        $expected = [
            ['id' => 1, 'title' => 'First Article'],
            ['id' => 2, 'title' => 'Second Article'],
            ['id' => 3, 'title' => 'Third Article']
        ];

        $this->assertEquals($expected, $result);
    }
}
```

With Pest, it will become:

```
beforeEach(function () {
    $this->Articles = TableRegistry::getTableLocator()->get('Articles');
});

test('findPublished', function () {
    $query = $this->Articles->find('published');

    expect($query)->toBeInstanceOf('Cake\ORM\Query');

    $result = $query->enableHydration(false)->toArray();
    $expected = [
        ['id' => 1, 'title' => 'First Article'],
        ['id' => 2, 'title' => 'Second Article'],
        ['id' => 3, 'title' => 'Third Article']
    ];

    expect($result)->toBe($expected);
});
```

Note that `toBeInstanceOf()` and `toBe()` are part of the available [Pest expectations](https://pestphp.com/docs/expectations).

Finally, instead of running your test suite with `$ ./vendor/bin/phpunit`, you will run it with `$ ./vendor/bin/pest`.

Comment: Fine answer, although understanding how to implement Cake fixture loading line in Pest would be really helpful. Having some kind of idea of how to use fixtures or fixture factories (https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/development/testing.html#fixture-factories) in Pest would be nice. Not sure if that is possible?